# Ошибка Missing argument 2 for

Tags: php

В логах сайта нашёл постоянную ошибку:

> PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for EVPL_Options::child(), called in
> /home/f/fruit0006/Home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/events-and-places/payment-gateways/paykeeper.php
> on line 44 and defined in
> /home/f/fruit0006/Home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/events-and-places/admin/class-options.php
> on line 36
> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/f/fruit0006/Home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/events-and-places/admin/class-options.php on line 38

paykeeper.php 44 строка:

```
        function child_options($child){

        $opt = new EVPL_Options();

        $child .= $opt->child(
            array(
                'name'=>'connect_sale',
                'value'=>$this->form_pay_id
            )
        );

        return $child;
    }
```

class-options.php 36 строчка

```
    function child($args,$conts){
    $return = '<div class="child-select '.$args['name'].'" id="'.$args['name'].'-'.$args['value'].'">';
    foreach($conts as $content){
        $return .= $content;
    }
    $return .= '</div>';
    return $return;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста устранить проблему. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: И не можешь ее перевести?

Comment: При чём тут перевести, я не могу её решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод принимает два аргумента, его вызов происходит с одним аргументом, значит нужно добавить второй аргумент который судя по контексту должен быть контентом в теге

например

```
function child_options($child){

    $opt = new EVPL_Options();
    $args = [
        'name'=>'connect_sale',
        'value'=>$this->form_pay_id,
    ];
    $conts = [
        'test data',
    ];


    $child .= $opt->child($args, $conts);

    return $child;
}
```

Comment: Это как, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: у вас есть метод 'child' который принимает два аргумента child($args, $conts) соответсвенно при вызове этого метода ему нужно передавать два аргумента, у вас же при вызове этого метода передается один аргумент - массив с параметрами, вам нужно передать в этот метод еще один аргумент который должен быть массивом с данными.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.